# macOS: Alias or symlink to 'new' app does not work

Tags: macos, symbolic-link, alias

On my Mac I migrated my text editor to a different one. The old one is the now 'archived' Atom editor and the new one is VSCodium.

Many 'default' file types point to 'Atom' so that does not work any more after uninstalling Atom. So I put a symlink
`ln -s /Applications/VSCodium.app /Application/Atom.app`
That does not work when I click in a file browser on e.g. a .php or .js file which is associated to Atom. I'd expect that the symlink diverts it to VSCodium.
But when I run `open -a Atom`, then VSCodium does start.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, as you didn't specify what "archived" means and what exactly happens when you double-click a file now - if "archived" means you uninstalled Atom, I believe nothing happens. I think the misunderstanding is that an .app isn't actually an application, it's a "package", i.e. a folder.

When your .php-file is associated with Atom and you double-click it, MacOS uses binary file `/Applications/Atom.app/Content/MacOS/Atom` to open the file. Changing Atom.app to a symlink doesn't change the association, just the path, so double-clicking causes MacOS to search for `/Applications/VSCodium.app/Content/MacOS/Atom` which doesn't exist.

You need to change the file associations one by one:

- Right-click the file
- Choose **Get Info**
- Choose the application you want to use with **Open with:** drop-down box